# Does anyone know about Ramanujan's method of solving the quartic?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, quartics

I have read (probably) in Kanigel's book *The Man Who Knew Infinity* that S. Ramanujan devised his own method of solving the Quartic Equation after he learnt to solve the Cubic Equation. Does anyone know what exactly was Ramanujan's method of solving the Quartic Equation?

---

**Update**

It is now asked [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/613/does-anyone-know-about-ramanujans-method-of-solving-the-quadratic) at HSMSE.

Comment: This would be right at home at [hsm.se]

Comment: @WarmFuzzies: Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Aryabhata: No. It's quadratic.

Comment: You must have it wrong. Compared to cubic equations, solving quadratic equations is child's play.

Comment: @TonyK, it's possible Kanigel used the wrong word.  user170039, can you supply a page reference?

Comment: The [help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) mentions "History and development of mathematics" as being on-topic for math.stackexchange.  Also, here are some [similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101376/how-did-hermite-calculate-e-pi-sqrt163-in-1859) [questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659153/theorem-that-von-neumann-proved-in-five-minutes) which were highly upvoted. I think this question is on-topic here.

Comment: The [MacTutor History of Mathematics](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Ramanujan.html) says that "Ramanujan was shown how to solve cubic equations in 1902 and he went on to find his own method to solve the quartic."

Comment: @PerManne: Then I must have mistaken. Actually I have read it a while ago so I may be wrong.

Comment: I have removed the soft-question tag. This has a completely objective answer: the method used by Ramanujan.

Comment: This question has also been asked on [History of Science and Math Stack Exchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/613/128), where it will likely find a better audience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find it in ***Ramanujan's Notebooks IV*** by B. Berndt, Chap. 22 Elementary Results, ***Entry 20***, p.31.

Ramanujan starts with this problem. Let $a,b,c,d$ be arbitrary. Solve the system,

$$x^2+ay = b\tag{20a}$$

$$y^2+cx = d\tag{20b}$$

Eliminating $y$, we find it is equivalent to,

$$a^2(d-cx) = (b-x^2)^2\tag{20.1}$$

Assume without loss of generality that $a=2$. Expanding this out,

$$x^4-2bx^2+4cx+(b^2-4d)=0\tag{20.1a}$$

By a simple linear substitution, the general quartic equation can be expressed in the *depressed form*,

$$x^4+px^2+qx+r = 0\tag{20.1b}$$

Equating coefficients of ${20.1a}$ and ${20.1b}$, you have a system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns {$b,c,d$}. Hence ***every*** quartic can be expressed in the form ${20.1}$. The problem then is to find $x$. Ramanujan defines,

$$x = \alpha+\beta+\gamma\tag{20.1c}$$

$$y = -(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)$$

$$-c/2 = \alpha\beta\gamma$$

(If you are familiar with cubic equations, you'll already see where Ramanujan is going.)

Substitute $x,y,c$ into $(20a)$ and $(20b)$ keeping in mind $a=2$, then,

$$x^2+ay = \alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2= b$$

$$y^2+cx = (\alpha\beta)^2+(\beta\gamma)^2+(\gamma\alpha)^2 = d$$

$$(-c/2)^2 = (\alpha\beta\gamma)^2$$

By elementary symmetric polynomials, we then conclude that $\alpha^2,\,\beta^2,\,\gamma^2$ are roots of the cubic equation,

$$t^3-bt^2+dt-c^2/4=0\tag{20.1d}$$

Of course, by solving $(20.1d)$, one can then find $\alpha,\,\beta,\,\gamma$. Using $(20.1c)$, we then further conclude that the four roots of the quartic are,

$$x = \alpha+\beta+\gamma, \quad\alpha-\beta-\gamma, \quad-\alpha-\beta+\gamma, \quad-\alpha+\beta-\gamma$$

**P.S.** This is similar to Euler's method where he solves a quartic as $x_i = \sqrt{y_1}\pm \sqrt{y_2}\pm \sqrt{y_3}$ and the $y_i$ are roots of a cubic. There's actually a generalization to this for solvable *8th deg eqns* as $x_i = \sqrt{y_1}\pm \sqrt{y_2}\pm\dots\pm \sqrt{y_7}$ and the $y_i$ are roots of a *7th deg eqn*. See this [mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145145/on-the-solvable-octic-x8-x729x229-0).

Comment: @littleO: That _similar_ question just happened to be mine.  :)

Comment: Can the same method be used to find a formula for the sextic?

Comment: @Frank: No, this method takes advantage of the fact that $n=4$ is a power of $2$. There is a similar approach for $n=8$ (see this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145145/on-the-solvable-octic-x8-x729x229-0)) though is solvable in radicals only if the octic has a solvable Galois group.

Comment: It has been many years since this answer, and I am not sure if you are still using MO, Can I ask you something?
What do you think was the motivation for Ramanujan for setting the system (20a) and (20b)?
Wikipedia says "Ramanujan was shown how to solve cubic equations in 1902; he developed his own method to solve the quartic".
He was 15 at that time and all he read was S. L. Loney's "Trigonometry".
Maybe there are no motivations for him to come up with the solutions? Just pure talent and intuition behind it?
What do you think?